# Dealing with a collegue with habit of spitting

Tags: software-industry, communication, team, india

I am a junior android developer. I work in a startup. 
I have one colleague in android department .

**He has a habit of spitting**. 
If he does not like somebody's opinion. He spit on on the floor in front of that person. He does that to express his disagreement.

Suppose He makes an android app. He asks you for your feedback. If your feedback is negative. He will spit either in the air towards you or on the ground in front of you.

If someone is not supporting him in his sick schemes. He spits in the air towards a person.

If he is offended by something you did or said . He spits.

When someone asks why he did it. He says He was chewing tobacco or something else. 
Or he cannot swallow his saliva. Or some other  clever cover up.

He is the only colleague who has this habit.
It is very disgusting for someone siting next to him. It upsets me. It makes sick. I am unable to do my task properly. I do get distracted.

*How should I deal with this?*

*What should I do?*

**Edit: what have I done so far ?**

I tried to convince my colleague to not to do that. But he did not change his habit. I said *"please Do not  spit in office. It is not professional. It is highly inappropriate"*. But it did not work.

**Edit 2:  How should I report this behaviour to my superiors?**

**Edit 3: Is this common behaviour?**

**Edit 4: what would you do if your colleague does same?**

**Edit 5: Is it common that someone spit in office?**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93516/discussion-on-question-by-aman-dealing-with-a-collegue-with-habit-of-spitting).

Comment: It says you need 20 reputation on stackexchange network to chat. How am i supposed to chat ?  What can i do? @Mister Positive

Comment: @Aman you now have 20+ reps :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a fellow IT engineer from India, this is absolutely disgusting behavior. It is neither common nor professionally acceptable. I would advise you to take the below steps:

1. Ask him to stop. You mentioned you have already tried this with no effect.
2. Talk to your manager about this. Tell him everything you have told us.
3. If manager doesn't do anything, talk to HR.
4. If after all this nothing happens, then find a new job and leave the company.

(I would say, transfer to a different project/account/department; but as a startup they probably don't have many positions for an Android developer.)

A place that does not value cleanliness and professionalism won't teach you anything worthwhile.

Comment: is it common in companies in india? Since I am a fresher. I do not about other companies. @Paresh

Comment: No, it's not common. Talk to your supervisors.

Answer (score 10):

> How should I deal with this?
>   What should I do?

If you have already asked your coworker to stop this in a polite way, and did not work, you should *take this to your manager/superior*, so they can sort this out the way they see fit.

IANAL, nor I live in India, but a quick Google search seems to indicate that not only is this unhealthy, but also seems to be penalized by Indian law, so this is surely something this coworker shouldn't be doing at all.

Comment: thanks I was upset. I really needed to talk to someone about this. +1 for your answer. I cannot upvote.Since  My reputation is less than 15.

Comment: @Aman I can see why you were upset. Just remember to keep it polite and professional also when raising this with your manager, keeping it as objective and non-emotional as possible. Also, does this spitting also disturb other coworkers of yours?

Comment: How should I report this behaviour to my superiors? @DarkCygnus

Comment: @Aman try approaching your manager, and asking them for a moment. Then in privately expose the situation, explain how it affects you and others, and ask for help on what steps to take.

Answer (score 3):

His behaviour is beyond unacceptable.

> When someone asks why he did it. He says He was chewing tobacco or something else. Or he cannot swallow his saliva. Or some other clever cover up.

If it were me, I'd directly confront him on that.

> Sorry, but that's a lie. You're doing this *every time* someone disagrees with you, whenever you get negative feedback, or whenever you feel someone has offended you. It's beyond unprofessional, it's unhygienic, demeaning, and quite frankly disgusting. If you really feel the need to do it, take yourself into the bathroom first and do it in private.

Some people simply need someone to stand up to them in front of others, and then they'll become rather embarrassed and stop.

...but I also realise that not everyone is able to be that confrontational. In any case, you *definitely* take it to your manager, and you also need to start making a log of every time this happens - note down dates, times, and the run up of events immediately before. When you've got a log over a few weeks, submit that to your manager and/or HR as evidence.

Comment: our office does not have ideal or professional environment. My colleague thinks its acceptable to spit. He thinks I should do the same if i am offended. But is that beneath my dignity. I was upset about this behaviour. Is it common that people spit when they are angry? @berry120

Comment: @Aman If he thinks you should do the same if you're offended, then he's *admitting* that it's not for health / other reasons, so his argument for why he's doing it falls flat on its face. I'm not in India, but certainly in my culture i've never seen someone do it, and if someone did I'd imagine everyone else around them reacting with contempt & disgust.